# Umbraco copy-of not showing xml markup

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I’m using Umbraco 4.7.0

My goal is to get the image path from a hard coded media node id of 4191. If I create a new macro with the code:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(4191, false())"/>
```

I get the output:

> /media/17675/my image.jpg50033618497jpg

I was expecting some well formed xml, however, it appears I’m missing all the tags. I therefore cannot reference the path for the image directly.

Am I missing something really simple here?

**EDIT**

I discovered how to get the raw xml output from my `copy-of` statement. I needed to wrap it in a `<textarea>` tag:

```
  <textarea>
      <xsl:copy-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(4191, false())"/>
  </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(4191, 0)/umbracoFile"/>
```

See also http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getmedia